# Running Spring Boot CLI using the command, 'spring run app.groovy' is giving, "bash: spring: command not found" error

Tags: angularjs, web-services, spring-rest

In git bash, executing:

```
$ spring run app.groovy
```

gives error,

> bash: spring: command not found

In app.groovy

```
@Controller class JsApp { }
```

Comment: try `spring --version`, looks like spring is not in the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like spring is not in the path, please refer [installation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-sdkman-cli-installation)

**Shell Completion**

Shell auto-completion scripts are provided for BASH and ZSH. Add symlinks to the appropriate
location for your environment. For example, something like:

ln -s ./shell-completion/bash/spring /etc/bash_completion.d/spring

Comment: Thankyou @jos for your answer. SDKMan seems to install well, but rest of the steps, source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" gives No such file or directory